tkinter, widgets and OOP Placing in windows
Trying to understand how to specify which window will hold which widget.
I am having difficulty with something that seems incredibly basic, but I can’t see it.
The following is from Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tkinter):
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, root=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.medialLabel = tk.Label(self, text='Hello World')
        self.medialLabel.config(bg="#00ffff")
        self.medialLabel.grid()
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.quit)
        self.quitButton.grid()

app = Application()
app.root = tk.Tk()
app.root.title('Sample application')
app.mainloop()


My questions:
Why do 2 windows popup? How do I re-write this to have the widgets show in the “Sample application” window? How could I change this to show the label in one window and the button in another using OOP?
I have eliminated “root” from the code: no change in output. Eliminating self.grid() shows 2 empty windows, as does eliminating the function and moving the label & button to the main code. tk.Frame appears to do nothing

When app (a tk.Frame) is created, a root window will be created implicitly.  So app.root is the second root window.
You can create the root window explicitly first and then create instance of Application:
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, root=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        #self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.medialLabel = tk.Label(self, text='Hello World')
        self.medialLabel.config(bg="#00ffff")
        self.medialLabel.grid()
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.quit)
        self.quitButton.grid()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Sample application')
app = Application(root)
app.grid()
root.mainloop()


Or you can simply make Application inheriting from tk.Tk instead:
class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Sample application')
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.medialLabel = tk.Label(self, text='Hello World')
        self.medialLabel.config(bg="#00ffff")
        self.medialLabel.grid()
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.quit)
        self.quitButton.grid()

Application().mainloop()


Thank you! You answered my question perfectly, albeit, indirectly. I could not wrap my head around why 2 windows pop up, then I saw that, in addition to commenting out self.grid() (which I had tried), you moved it out of the class def to just before root.mainloop() and finally the code works as expected. That was also my mistake when I tried re-writing it as your second example. A classic case of "I don't see it until I see it" for me. I'm incredibly grateful.
